# Stop two threads when back button is pressed

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-activity

When I give my thread name it is showing that it cannot resolve the symbol. I want to stop the thread and go to an index page `(indexactivity)` when the back button is pressed

```
public class page2 extends ActionBarActivity {
    ImageView b2;
    int count = 0;
    Handler handler = null;
    Handler handler1 = null;
    Runnable j = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page2);

        Intent c = getIntent();
        String name = c.getStringExtra("t");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        b2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redball);

        // Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(page2.this, R.anim.fade);
        // Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.activity_move);

        // b2.startAnimation(animation);
        // b2.startAnimation(animation1);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                count = count + 1;
                Intent intentVibrate = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VibrateService.class);
                startService(intentVibrate);
            }
        });

        handler1 = new Handler();
        j = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams =
                        (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) b2.getLayoutParams();

                DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

                Random r = new Random();

                absParams.x = r.nextInt(width);
                absParams.y = r.nextInt(height);
                b2.setLayoutParams(absParams);
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(page2.this, R.anim.fade);
                b2.startAnimation(animation);
                handler1.postDelayed(j, 870);
            }
        };
        handler1.postDelayed(j, 50);

        handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable t = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Page3.class);
                d.putExtra("count", count);
                d.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(d);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(t, 8000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_page2, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(t);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

This is the place where it found an error.

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot resolve symbol t` is coming because you have declared this variable inside `onCreate()` method and trying to use it in a different method to remove the callback. Follow the same approach of definition as you have done for your variable `j`

Define this `Runnable` at class level like this

```
final Runnable t = null; // if you need final keep it, otherwise remove it
```

and change

```
final Runnable t = new Runnable() {
```

to

```
t = new Runnable() {
```

Comment: ya when i have given this code,error at t has been removed but a new error has occured at overide  ... error is " method does not override method from super class" ..   y is it??

Comment: I would suggest you to remove the method `onBackPress()` and put code `handler.removeCallbacks(t);` inside `onStop()`. This method will be called when you leave the current activity and go to the new one.

Comment: @Override// error is at override,
public boolean onBackPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {                                                         error is-(method does not override method from super class)                                  i tried giving it in onstop but still error is occuring at overide

Comment: try what I suggest in my last comment.